# Latent Awakening in Shadowrun 5

Tags: character-creation, shadowrun-sr5, shadowrun-sr4, edition-comparison

My group wants to change the edition from Shadowrun 4 to Shadowrun 5. We want to convert our characters, and one of us has the advantage 'Latent Awakening'. I didn't find an advantage like this in the Shadowrun 5 Core Rulebook.

Is there something similar (probably in an addon rulebook), or is there a suggestion on how we can implement it through character creation?

My first idea was to "jump in time" so the character is already awakened when we start our SR5 campaign, but that would steal all the fun for the person who wants to play out his awakening.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *easiest* way to do this would be to start the character Awakened with a custom Disadvantage that blocks access to his magic until he buys off the Disadvantage.  Build the character normally as an SR5 character and assign a Karma bonus (and thus, cost) to the "you can't use your magic yet" Disadvantage, and let him buy it off at a dramatically appropriate time.

If you don't want to have to deal with the minutiae of getting a bonus at creation and having pay back more later, you could just make the Disadvantage worth zero Karma.  Then he can "pay it off" later at the low, low price of 0 x 2 = 0 Karma.

Comment: I like that. There's the risk that it could be invalidated by an upcoming rulebook, though...

Comment: @Nigralbus I hope and pray that 90% of the corebook is invalidated by future releases.  Especially all the chapters that involve magic or technology.

Comment: I think we'll do the first suggestion. The player has to buy "Latent Awakening", our custom disadvantage, for 10 Karma. When  the time has come and he awakens, he gets 2 points in magic and the advantage 'aspect magician'. For his first spell he'll have to pay with the karma he gains during the campaign (but I will not tell him how much that costs). So pretty adopted from the 4th edition. Does this sound fair?

Comment: @Ferox a disadvantage GIVES Karma at character creation, and costs twice as much to remove after creation.  I was saying let him build the character with all his starting spells and Magic rating, etc, and give him some Karma for the disadvantage that turns his magic off.  Later in the game, he can pay the Karma (20, if you give him 10 at character creation for it) to buy off the Disadvantage and get the whole kit.  (He should probably pick a fairly low magic priority, unless you're ok with him awakening to powerful magic all at once.)

Comment: Ah sorry, yes, I meant advantage. Your suggestion would work and be much easier, but the Player doesnt want to pick the magic he will get. He wants a dramatic Story where I (the gm) chooses to awaken him.

Comment: Ah, I see.  You could still have him build the character normally using my suggestion if you chose, and simply choose his starting spells he would get normally from his Magic Priority yourself, if he wanted.  ^_^